# moving to svg from canvas

Tags: html, svg, html5-canvas

I have been using HTML5 canvas for making animations in my apps since last one year. All is working well and fine but I absolutely loath the graphic quality and resolution that canvas provides. I am absolutely amazed when I compare the graphic quality between SVG and canvas and hence I want to move to SVG animations rather than using canvas. But the problem is that I am unable to understand how can I make the same animations that are there in canvas to work in SVG.

Certain, or rather most of my animations include sprite animations (rendering images from sprite and animating them using redrawing canvas). I wonder if that can be done using SVG because I don't want to use canvas for sprite animations and SVG for other animations separately. Are there any good tutorials or starting point for making SVG animations ? Any info will be useful. Thanks!

Comment: Like Canvas, you have transforms available in SVG to do your animations (translate, rotate, scale, etc).  Transforms behave much like canvas transforms, but if you're doing multiple like-kind transforms on the same object you'll need to aggregate them yourself (SVG transforms are non-cumulative).  There is also an animate property built into SVG--don't use it. Do your animation with javascript instead.  You ask for a starting point?  Put an SVG rect on the page and animate it using transforms:  Try-Fail-Adjust-TryAgain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D3 is good. I would also tell you to check http://raphaeljs.com/ makes your life easier.

When it comes to animation it is tempting to go along HTML5 canvas but if your need is complex animations or require more control and quality, SVG is the way to go.

1. Apart from quality the other cons in HTML5 are behind the scenes it is a pixel manipulation, and you would not get DOM for each object meaning you cannot call them by ID or manipulate them singularly. Every small change is redraw.
2. SVG on the other hand gives DOM level of control and supported by webkits